# 400 error (Bad Request) creating a Page with Experience Manager

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have an SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 image in which Experience Manager is installed. I can successfully browse my staging site, log in to ExM and change content and pages. However, when I try to create a new page I get a 400 (Bad Request) error. This is the logged error:

> Unable to update the changes using OData Service.
>   The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>
> Component: Tridion.SiteEdit.FastTrackPublishing
>   Errorcode: 1003
>   User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> StackTrace Information Details:
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.BatchRequest(Boolean replaceOnUpdate)
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
>      at Tridion.SiteEdit.FastTrackPublishing.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
>
>      at Tridion.SiteEdit.FastTrackPublishing.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
>      at SyncInvokePreview(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

I've just checked the CD log file and can see this error:

> 012-10-16 12:29:05,782 ERROR JPADAOFactory - Unable to load JPA DAO with name: TrackedRequest and class: com.tridion.storage.TrackedRequestDAO due too exception in DAO construction
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TrackedRequestDAO' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/ASP.NET/Preview/httpupload/bin/lib/tracking_core.jar!/com/tridion/storage/TrackedRequestDAO.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.tridion.storage.TrackedRequestDAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unexpected dialect encountered: . TrackedRequest item type should be configured to use a supported database.

Inline editing was enabled for the already published content when I received the image but I needed to create the Content Type and Page Type myself. I did this in the usual manner, creating a Page, flagging it as a Page Type, adding the prototype content to it, and configuring the settings for naming and storage (for the created content). I also restarted IIS, shutdown the COM+ package and restarted the Tridion Service Host and Publisher services.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error, and how to fix it?

**EDIT**

So the error suggests it's an issue in the storage config. Here are the relevant sections:

```xml
  <Storage Id="trackingDB" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" Type="persistence" dialect="MSSQL">
    <Pool CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="5" Type="jdbc"/>
    <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
      <Property Name="serverName" Value="SDLPE.pe.local"/>
      <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433"/>
      <Property Name="databaseName" Value="tridion_tracking"/>
      <Property Name="user" Value="encrypted:u9aIOj9uX2IcL1rI6U5ndA=="/>
      <Property Name="password" Value="encrypted:vprUfrnluvIQAVRNSMTx5g=="/>
    </DataSource>
  </Storage>
```

And:

```xml
<Item cached="true" typeMapping="TrackedRequest" storageId="trackingDB"/>
```

**EDIT**

I've just been trawling through the log file and found this:

> 2012-10-16 14:12:43,148 DEBUG ConfigurationItemTypeLoader - Loaded mapping: trackedrequest to storage: trackingDB
>   2012-10-16 14:12:43,148 DEBUG ConfigurationItemTypeLoader - Loaded mapping: trackingbatch to storage: trackingDB
>   2012-10-16 14:12:43,148 DEBUG ConfigurationItemTypeLoader - Loaded mapping: synchronizationrecord to storage: trackingDB
>   2012-10-16 14:12:43,148 DEBUG ConfigurationItemTypeLoader - Loaded mapping: trackingitem to storage: trackingDB

It seems that the config should be picked up correctly, but still it can't read the dialect propely from the relevant storage definition.

Comment: I have only ever seen this error when the staging website's application pool identity is ApplicationPoolIdentity. Changing it to NetworkService fixed it for me. Might be something to check.

Comment: The app pool is configured for a different specific identity. Just trying to find out why, although it's like this in another system that does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end the issue was related to having Page Metadata specified for the Page Type. The errors I was seeing logged don't affect the performance of the website so were misleading me.