# 400 error when creating a new page via Tridion Experience Manager (UI)

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, experience-manager

I have a similar problem to [400 error (Bad Request) creating a Page with Experience Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914834/400-error-bad-request-creating-a-page-with-experience-manager), however, I get a different error message.

When creating a new page via the UI a 404 occurs.  The page is created inside the Content Manager with the prototype content, but not published to Staging, i.e. there is no publish transaction added to the publishing queue.  So when the iFrame contents are refreshed pointing to the new page's URL there is nothing there, hence the 404.

The Event Viewer log shows:

```
Concurrent access to Session object detected. Thread (41) and (3) trying to access same Session concurrently. Session objects are not thread-safe!
```

The CD logs show nothing other than (what looks like) irrelevant debug output.

I have tried creating a blank HTML page, se_blank.html, as per the documentation (http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/task_2F3D125DF7274CC9BE33BBBDC284D314), but no avail.

Can someone please provide some further guidance here?

Answer (score 2):

When new Page is created two things should happen:
 - Page should be sent for Publishing
 - Session Preview should be generated for new Page and you'll be redirected to it

First step might fail if there is no Publication Target configured for new Page
Second could fail if:

- you turned off Session Preview in the settings
- Session Preview is not correctly configured
- you have different from default Page path routing settings on the staging web site. By default it's Publication Path + Structured Group(s) Path + Page filename

Comment: Hi Boris, turns out I had a problem in my wrapper config preventing the publishing.  However, the 404 problem remains.  The issue is that the UI redirects to the new page before the web server is ready to serve the page, i.e. it does it 1 second too soon.  Is there a way to delay the refresh and redirect ever so slightly?

Comment: As I said before, the Session Preview should be triggered, so you would not see 404 error.